# How to search for a string inside an ArrayList of a class

Tags: java, search, arraylist

```
/**
 * @param title title of the movie to search for
 * @return the movie with the given title 
 * or null if there is no movie in the library with that title
 */
public Movie findMovieByTitle(String title)
{
    for (Movie movie : movies){
        if(movies.contains(title)){
        return title;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

How can I find the title in the ArrayList? There are similar topics to this but they deal with a String ArrayList, I'm searching for a title in another class. Do I need to make a local variable and call a method from the Movie class?

This is the Movie class:

```
public class Movie
{
    private String title;
    private int runLength;  // length of the movie in minutes
    private int starRating; // rating from 1 to 4 stars (0 = not rated yet)

/**
 * Create a movie with the title, run length, and number of stars given
 * @param aTitle title of the movie
 * @param aRunLength run length of the movie in minutes
 * @param aStarRating star rating of the movie, a value from 1 to 4 inclusive
 */
public Movie(String aTitle, int aRunLength, int aStarRating)
{
    title = aTitle;
    runLength = aRunLength;
    setStarRating(aStarRating);
}

/**
 * Create a movie with the title and run length given
 * @param aTitle title of the movie
 * @param aRunLength run length of the movie in minutes
 */
public Movie(String aTitle, int aRunLength)
{
    title = aTitle;
    runLength = aRunLength;
    starRating = 0;
}

/**
 * @return title of the movie
 */
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

/**
 * @return run length of the movie in minutes
 */
public int getRunLength()
{
    return runLength;
}

/** 
 * @return rating in stars of the movie; a value of 0 means "not rated"
 */
public int getStarRating()
{
    return starRating;
}

/**
 * Set the star rating of this movie to the value given
 * @param newRating new star rating of the movie
 */
public void setStarRating(int newRating)
{
    if (newRating >= 1 && newRating <= 4) {
        starRating = newRating;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error: Valid range for star rating is 1 to 4");
    }
}

/**
 * Reset the star rating of this movie to "not rated"
 */
public void resetStarRating()
{
    starRating = 0;
}

/**
 * Increase the star rating of this movie by 1
 */
public void increaseStarRating()
{
    if (starRating < 4) {
        starRating = starRating + 1;
    }
}

/**
 * Decrease the star rating of this movie by 1
 */
public void decreaseStarRating()
{
    if (starRating > 1) {
        starRating = starRating - 1;
    }
}

/**
 * Print information on this movie
 */
public void printMovieInfo()
{
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println("Run length: " + runLength);
    if (starRating == 0) {
        System.out.println("Rating: (no rating)");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Rating: " + starRating + " stars");
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

}

Comment: `if (movie.getTitle().equals(title)`? And shouldn't you be returning `Movie` and not `title`?

Comment: Would the return statement be `true`?

Comment: your method definition should be like public string findMovieByTitle(String title)   --  because it is returning String not Movie.

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: and you can lose the for loop if movies is an ArrayList.

Comment: @shreshtabm it's an exercise and the method headings are already pre-written for us, we just have to write the actual methods. I don't understand what I am supposed to return? It says return the title but Java won't let me.

Comment: It says return the movie with the given title and not the title itself. Read the comments for the method @feelingstoned

Comment: If you want to get an effective answer, you need to show how Movie class is declared.

Comment: @shreshtabm I posted the Movie class source code

Comment: @feelingstoned Check my answer and let me know it works

Comment: @feelingstoned your else loop is wrong. If you use it that way, it checks the title only with the first movie else it will return null.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Movie findMovieByTitle(String title) {
    return movies.stream() // open a stream on the movies collection
        .filter(movie -> movie.getTitle().equals(title)) // filter them based on their title
        .findFirst() // get the first matching item
        .get(); // this might throw NoSuchElementException if no element found
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this won't compile because `findFirst` returns `Optional<T>` - this is to deal with the `null` problem that every other answer is struggling with. So you need to change the return type or call `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work

```
public Movie findMovieByTitle(String title)
{
    for (Movie movie : movies){
        if(movie.getTitle().equals(title)){
        return movie;
}
}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had something similar to this but I had an else statement with a `return null;` but just by taking it out it worked

Comment: I would recommend throwing an `Exception` rather that using `null` - in modern Java `null` should be avoided if possible.